# creating shared library using prebuilt static library using Android.mk

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I am trying to build a shared library using prebuilt static library, the respective Android.mk file is below.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
 #Include kerne headers in a proper way later on
 #LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../kernel/include
LOCAL_MODULE := sensors.$(TARGET_BOARD_PLATFORM)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false

LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_SHARED_LIBRARIES)/hw

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := LibFusion_ARM_cpp
 #LOCAL_LDFLAGS := $(LOCAL_PATH)/LibFusion_ARM_cpp.a

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblog libcutils
 #include any shared library dependencies
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libimu.a
LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := sensors_u8500.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The files present in the folder is 
Android.mk ,  LibFusion_ARM_cpp.a , libimu.a , MEMSAlgLib_eCompass.h , sensors_u8500.cpp

The error what I am getting while building is below,

```
**make: *** No rule to make target `out/target/product/u8500/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/LibFusion_ARM_cpp_intermediates/LibFusion_ARM_cpp.a', needed by `out/target/product/u8500/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/sensors.montblanc_intermediates/LINKED/sensors.montblanc.so'.  Stop.**
```

What is the issue here?

Unable to build the shared library. I mean unable to generate libsensor.so file. facing the above mentioned error. ** make: *** No rule to make target

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the build system cannot find `LibFusion_ARM_cpp.a`. AFAIK, you have to first specify a pre-built library module using `PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY` with `LibFusion_ARM_cpp.a` set as `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` and `LOCAL_MODULE` as `LibFusion_ARM_cpp`. This will basically copy the specified static library to the default directory the build system searches through for all of the necessary modules.

Answer (score 0):

I did two things to understand the case:

A. In the above shown make file, I added the below so as to ensure that this .a file gets copied into the build.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := LibFusion_ARM
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := LibFusion_ARM_cpp.a
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

When I build it using `mm -n`, command I see this strange statement `rm -f ...` of the LibFusion_ARM.a. Of course the build fails saying it's not able to locate the `STATIC LIB`.

```
mkdir -p out/target/product/u8500/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/LibFusion_ARM_intermediates/  
rm -f out/target/product/u8500/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/LibFusion_ARM_intermediates/LibFusion_ARM.a  
echo "target StaticLib: LibFusion_ARM (out/target/product/u8500/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/LibFusion_ARM_intermediates/LibFusion_ARM.a)"
mkdir -p out/target/product/u8500/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/sensors.montblanc_intermediates/LINKED/
.
.
```

Why does this deletion happens? I am not sure. This is causing the problem. Please provide suggestions.

B. I added the below lines in the make file:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := LibFusion_ARM
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := LibFusion_ARM_cpp.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

I see the below error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `out/target/product/u8500/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/LibFusion_ARM_intermediates/LibFusion_ARM.a', needed by `out/target/product/u8500/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/sensors.montblanc_intermediates/LINKED/sensors.montblanc.so'.
Stop.
```

Clearly in the second case, the file LibFusion_ARM is not getting copied (even `obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/LibFusion_ARM_intermediates` directory is not created).
Needless to emphasis, if I manually copy the file LibFusion_ARM_cpp.a as LibFusion_ARM.a then the build goes through.